# Uploading files to SFDC attachment object using REST call

Tags: apex, rest-api, attachment, bulk-api

I have requirement to upload files to SFDC attachments object.
I am making REST call from my Java code to SFDC with required details.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://ap.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/Attachment/ \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer sessionId' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "ParentId":"00T0K0000243CvXXX",
    "Name":"Test123.txt",
    "body":"base64Coded"
}'
```

But above REST call support only single Attachment at a time. Is there any way I can upload multiple files in a single shot. Or can we leverage SFDC Bulk API anyhow?

Comment: What is the MAX file size I can upload using REST API calls. I tried and Salesforce threw exception on 25MB but I did not find any doc which confirm on the size limit. Can someone point me to the relevant doc link.

Comment: size limit (from this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm) is `You can insert or update blob data using a non-multipart message, but you are limited to 50 MB of text data or 37.5 MB of base64–encoded data.`

Comment: @davejagoda this to create document i guess and not for the attachment

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bulk API here to upload attachment in bulk.

- First, you need to Create a request.txt File which will include details of files.
- Then Create a Zip Batch File with Binary Attachments
- Then Create a Job for Batches with Binary Attachments
- Finally, Create a Batch with Binary Attachments.

You can follow the details steps from here: [Load Binary Attachments](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/binary_intro.htm)

Comment: Thanks Tushar. As far I understood, this will create a batch job in Saleaforce and will execute as soon as it get CPU. I can use batch Job id returned in the response for checking the completion status but once the job is completed how to check what are the attachments which got failed and what was the cause of failure.

Comment: @San You can use [Get Batch Results](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_batches_get_results.htm) to check the status.

Comment: As per the link, in request.txt file each row will represent one record, in my case it will be attachment file details including the content of file being uploaded under body column. Do we have size limit on request.txt because I could see SF doc says Batches size should not be more than 10MB? In my case individual file can go up to 25MB.

Comment: @San you need to give path here of your file.

Comment: Ohh, I did not understand. if I give path rather than content will SF take care of downloading from the source location and upload to SF Attachment. (we have our files stored at Amazon S3)

Comment: @San you need to create zip file of attachments. Check the link. This line `The following sample CSV file includes two Attachment records. The first record references an attachment1.gif binary file in the base directory of the zip file. The second record references an attachment2.doc binary file in the subdir subdirectory of the zip file.`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried above approach and it worked. Only the problem I am facing is with size of file, some of my files are having more than 10MB of size and even after compressing in ZIP we are unable to losing much in size.  Alternately I want to try another approach. Can this be done from Apex code itself. What I mean is from Apex I will make call to S3 and download bunch of files and save in Attachment object.

Comment: @San yes you can do that but you will not be able to handle large files due to governor limits. Although you can try Java and Heroku.

Comment: here you refer Heroku to be used as a Platform to execute Java or Heroku specifically give functionality to upload/download even larger files?  We have our external service deployed on AWS.

Comment: @San Heroku to be used as a Platform to execute Java